# Auto Connect to Public Network and then "Accept TOS"

Tags: networking, linux

I have a video installation in a Museum for this summer. Currently there is a USB drive in the Pi that has an auto-login / bash.rc file to automatically play *.mp4 files in Omxplayer in order then loop.

This is all and great, but, every week I have to go into the Museum on the other side of town and update the USB stick with a new .mp4. I want to SFTP up a new file to the USB drive remotely so I don't have to drive across down weekly.

The Museum has an open wifi network, which I've seen "Auto-Connect" wifi scripts, but there's an "Accept" page of their TOS. The museum is owned by a University and "clean" wifi access can not be granted.

How would I go about this? Could I do a `curl` of google.com, if I get a page that matches a `grep` of the TOS, do a POST on the "ACCEPT" button?

Just curious if anyone's had a Pi in a remote location using free wifi that has these interstitial webpages of TOS.

Comment: this question is not specific to RPi, you may get better answers on superuser @ stackexchange.

Comment: @lenik Not necessarily. Super User tends to be very strict in what it allows, mainly questions oriented to professional server admins, not general user questions. [so] would probably be your best bet on this one, maybe [unix.se]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your pi gets kicked off of the wifi after a period of time? Or do you just need to accept a TOS on first logon?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they will allow outside access to your computer like that. A better option would probably be to have your pi fetch content from a remote site periodically. That way you could publish your videos somewhere, and have the pi automatically download the new content.

This could be done with a small script similar to

```
pkill mplayer
wget http://contentpage.com/mycontent.tar.gz
tar -xf mycontent.tar.gz
mplayer mycontent/*
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is true, they will likely be filtering incoming connections from the external world.